# how to set an initial value on React.createRef() method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

I manage scrolling in my component with a ref that is the current scroll value. I cannot use state and setState, because when the user would be scrolling the setState method would make things really choppy and impossible. Hence, I decided to use refs that don't re render the component, but save the value when the component re renders.
My problem is that I cannot set an initial value for the ref. As I am using a class component I cannot use the simple useRef react hook that allows the initial value to be set easily... instead I use React.createRef() but when I put the value in the parenthesis () it doesn't seem to register it and is undefined until the user scrolls.
How can I fix that?
[image]

Here when the component updates (for example when a new message is sent), I want to make sure that it scrolls down to the newest message only if the user is not browsing older messages somewhere above.
[image]

Comment: `this.scrollPosition.current = 201`, right after you create it.

Comment: could you please provide your render and constructor code?

Comment: AFAIK passing params to createRef does not change anything. Refs are initialized with the ref attribute

Comment: @MartinGodzina I already have the solution from the comments. My render method would be too big to paste in here. I think you're right, the createRef method doesn't even await any arguments in the first place I think.

Comment: Please remove the pictures and replace them with the text of the code.

Comment: Why use a ref though? wouldn't just a class variable suffice?

Comment: @koox00 it seems that a class variable didn't have a persistant value between re renders of my component. For example if someone sent a message and it was added to the state array of messages using the setState method, that class variable was reset to its original value. That's why I decided to use a ref which, as I heard before, is persistant across component updates but does not update the component itself when it changes unlike state variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To set the initial value of a ref created by React.createRef, do something like the following:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props):

  this.scrollPosition = React.createRef();
  this.scrollPosition.current = 201;
}
```

I do want to mention though, that since you're in a class component, you probably don't need a ref. In function components, refs are often used the way you're using them: to have a mutable object which persists from render to render.

But in class components, you already *have* a mutable object which persists from render to render: `this`. So you can probably ditch the ref and just do:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.scrollPosition = 201;
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.state.message === "" && this.scrollPosition > 200) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `createRef` doesn't take an initial value, but I wrote a replacement for it:

```
export function createRef<T>(initialValue: T): {current: T};
export function createRef<T>(): {current: T|null};
export function createRef<T>(initialValue?: T): {current: T|null} {
    return {current: initialValue ?? null}
}
```